# What is the predicate part of the sentence in an "X is ___ed" pattern?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, sentence, diagramming

Basically, this derives from an NLP problem I am facing in software development.  NLP stands for "Natural Language Processing", and it is ML dependent.  Since it depends on ML, it is naturally slightly wrong almost all of the time.

In this case, an NLP tool I am using has decomposed one part of sentence one way, and a different similar sentence (below) another.

I need to know the truth.

---

> Ultimate Swirly Ice Cream Scoopers are usually overrated when one considers all of the scoopers one could buy.

In the sentence above, if:

- Subject: "Ultimate Swirly Ice Cream Scoopers"
- Verb: are
- Adverbial Clause: "when one considers all of the scoopers one could buy"

Then which part of the sentence is:

- "usually overrated"

In specific terms?

Or, equally, what is the component "are usually overrated"?

---

For more context, that component could be interrupted: "are usually, except when fully upgraded, overrated". And I'll need some important concepts and jargon to be able to research the appropriate tactic to extract "are usually overrated" using natural language automation tools.

Comment: You have the subject right. The predicate is the verb phrase "are usually overrated when one considers all of the scoopers one could buy". "Usually overrated" is not a grammatical unit, not a constituent, but part of the VP. It consists of the head of the AdjP "overrated" and its modifier "usually".

Comment: @BillJ Ah -- got it, then I was misled by one error and confused by one correct decomposition. Thank you, you may be surprised how much that impacted.

Comment: @BillJ If "usually overrated" is an AdjP, then why wouldn't it be a constituent?

Comment: @MarcInManhattan "Usually overrated" is an AdjP, the predicative complement of "are". The expression "when one considers" is best analysed as a separate constituent, an adjunct, not a dependent in (thus part of) the AdjP. In that analysis, which is to be preferred, the AdjP is indeed a constituent.

Comment: To be clear about what I just said to @MarcInManhattan: the first layer of the clause (the 'immediate constituents') is the subject + the whole of the VP "are usually overrated when one considers ... ". At the next level down, the predicator (verb) is "are", whose complement is the AdjP "usually overrated", so it is a constituent at that level.

Comment: The only *necessary* component of the predicate (apart from the verb ***are*** itself) is the word ***overrated***. All the rest is just optional extra detail.

Comment: @FumbleFingers but required if you are automatically analyzing a legal sentence.  I'll need some sort of word or jargon for the combination of those words for searching and whatnot.  If it is a "verb phrase" or "verb group", etc., that is crucial.

Comment: @Chris FF means grammatically necessary, not semantically necessary.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth got it -- this is all very helpful

Comment: As @EdwinAshworth says, I meant it's one of just three *grammatically* necessary elements: ***subject** (Ultimate Swirly Ice Cream Scoopers) + **copula verb** (are) + **adjective** (overrated)*. Where "usually" adverbially modifies the verb, and everything from "when" onwards looks to me like a "whole sentence adverbial phrase". There are many ways of describing the elements within an utterance though; you need to choose the terminology and analytical framework that makes most sense to you.

Comment: "Xs are usually overrated" can have two different meanings (1) as a group, Xs tend to be overrated by most people (2) taken individually an X is likely to be an overrated X. Compare "Usually tomatoes are red" (or equivalently "Tomatoes are usually red") and "Traffic lights are usually red".